# Pretty print HTML output with Koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pretty-print, koa, koa-router

Is there a way to have your HTML output that comes from a Jade template be beautified? Something similar to Express's `app.locals.pretty = true;` ? I'm using `koa-router` and `koa-views` if that is relevant.

**server.js**

```
const koa = require('koa');
const views = require('koa-views');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const router = require('./routes');

const app = koa();

app.use(serve(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(views(`${__dirname}/views`, { extension: 'jade' }));
app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const router = require('koa-router')();

router.get('/', function *() {
  yield this.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/index.jade**

```
html
  head
    title Hello
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')

  body
    h1 Hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
app.use(views(`${__dirname}/views`, { extension: 'jade', pretty:true}));
```

that should do the trick...
on the other hand, i use koa-jade instead of koa-views. My current code looks like this:

```
var Jade  = require('koa-jade');

var jade = new Jade({
    viewPath: path.resolve(__dirname,"jade"),
    debug: true,
    pretty: true,
    compileDebug: true,
    basedir: path.resolve(__dirname,"jade"),
    app:app
  })
```

in production mode i just set pretty to false...

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pretty option for `koa-views` :(

I guess I'll have to try out koa-jade, thanks.